# Python Django - CreateView for model with OneToOneField gets error "object has no attribute 'id' " while saving

Tags: python, django

```
class Organizer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ... some other fields

class EventTemplate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(Organizer)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=event_directory_path)
    # ... some other fields
```

Organizer has a primary key that is also a OneToOne relation with user.
Then I used a CreateView to insert a new EventTemplate:

```
class AddEventTemplateCreateView(CreateView):
    model = EventTemplate
    fields = ['title', 'category', 'organizer']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:organizer-account')
```

But when saving, the POST action on AddEventTemplateCreateView (mapped in urls.py as "add-event") gives this error:

> AttributeError at /add-event/
>
> 'Organizer' object has no attribute 'id'

while debugging I verified that all properties of EventTemplate and property Organizer are correctly binded.
There is no error with Category, but category has an attribute "id", while Organizer has only an attribute "user_id" as PK.
I think he's trying to get a property "id" by convention for Organizer too.
I could try to modify Organizer model removing explicit primary_key and then relying on an automatic PK 'id', but it seems to me to be an useless repetition.

Is there any property to be set, some solution or suggestion to make it work? Or it can't be done using CreateView?

Thank you!

**Edit:**
Full traceback is:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-event/

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'ubivado',
 'bootstrapform']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  256.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  222.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/ubivado_project/ubivado/views.py" in form_valid
  46.         return super(AddEventTemplateCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  201.         self.object = form.save()

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  451.             self.instance.save()

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  700.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  728.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  812.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  851.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1059.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  1019.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1019.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1018.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in pre_save_val
  968.         return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  311.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  90.         name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in generate_filename
  328.             directory_name, filename = os.path.split(self.upload_to(instance, filename))

File "/Users/redpelle/PycharmProjects/ubivado/ubivado_project/ubivado/models.py" in event_directory_path
  10.     return 'events/org_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.organizer.id, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), filename)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /add-event/
Exception Value: 'Organizer' object has no attribute 'id'
```

**Edit 2 (Solved):**

In models.py I had:

```
def event_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'events/org_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.organizer.id, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), filename)
```

I had to correct `instance.organizer.id` in `instance.organizer.user_id`.

I didn't notice that because PyCharm suggests me an "id" field with autocomplete. Thanks @Daniel Roseman

Comment: @ozgur Yes, for Organizer model PK is user_id and not id, but it is marked as "primary_key" so I assumed that engine is capable to recognize it and then use "user_id" instead of "id". Is it not so?

Comment: how do you validate POST data in `AddEventTemplateCreateView`?

Comment: I just added a method:
def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(AddEventTemplateCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
to AddEventTemplateCreateView class just to check data with a breakpoint.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Django always uses the `pk` alias target than referencing `id` directly, so it must be something in your code.